# Issue with Amabari Hortonworks Host clean up remove packages

Tags: centos7, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to setup the cluster again after doing ambari-reset.
First time during the hosts check I got around 180 warning messages, after running the python script python /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_agent/HostCleanup.py  I get 57 warnings mentioning :

The following packages should be uninstalled
The following packages should be uninstalled
Package
hive_2_3_0_0_2557.noarch    1.2.1.2.3.0.0-2557.el6  Installed on 3 hosts
......
oozie_2_3_0_0_2557.noarch   4.2.0.2.3.0.0-2557.el6  Installed on 3 hosts
.........................

But when I login to those hosts and try to do yum remove and package "hive_2_3_0_0_2557.noarch" it doesn't find the package.
I am not sure if I'm missing something.

Thanks.
JE

Comment: not sure why people downvoted your question at the time, sure the yum answer was expected, but I wasn't sure if the packages behaved in the same way as normal yum packages (if compared to version specific packages from hortonworks or anothe repo), so it was useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it worked for me by manually entering into that machine and executing : 
sudo yum erase package name.

Comment: yum -y remove package_name also worked for me